# jqplot Canvas Over lay Max and Min

Tags: javascript, canvas, jqplot

I have called the jqplot bubble renderer based on the event onchange of the combobox.
 means the bubble renderer gets called everytime user change the value of the combobox.which eventually provides different sets of data to the bubble renderer. following is the code:`

```
$.jqplot.config.enablePlugins= true;
    $.jqplot('bubbleChart2', [data], {
    title : 'Committed Hours Vs Delivered Hours',
        seriesDefaults : {
        renderer : $.jqplot.BubbleRenderer,
            rendererOptions : {
             bubbleGradients: true,
             varyBubbleColors: true,
             autoscaleBubbles: true,
            autoscalePointsFactor: -0.15,
            autoscaleMultiplier: 0.85,
            highlightMouseOver : true,
            escapeHtml:true,
            showLabels:false
        },
        shadow : true,
        shadowAlpha : 0.1
    },
    axesDefaults : {
        tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
         labelOptions: {
        fontFamily: 'Georgia, Serif',
        fontSize: '12pt',
        color: 'Green'},
    },
            axes : {
        xaxis : {
            renderer : $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            label : 'Committed %',
             labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
        },
        yaxis : {
            autoscale : false,
            label : 'Delivered %',
             renderer : $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
              labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
        }
    },
        grid:grid,
        canvasOverlay: {
        show: true,
        objects: [
        {line: {
                name: "Performance Indicator",
               start: [-200,-200],
               stop: [1200,2200],
                color: "#FF0000",
                lineCap: 'butt',
                shadow: false,
                shadowAlpha: -15,
                showTooltip: false,
                lineWidth: 2
            }},
           ]}
                }).replot();`
```

Now I have problem in couple of different areas of the plot.

1. canvas over lay start and stop.
2. The data range to plot bubbles will be different so some of the bubbles are really big ans some of them are really small which doesnt make any sense to the plot.

any suggestion will be appreciative for my work.